# Makefile deleted my fortran program

Tags: makefile

Hi I've never written a makefile before, but I tried my hand at it with my fortran90 final project and the makefile seems to have delete my main program. here's my makefile

```
# Sample makefile for several modules
#
FC = gfortran
final.x: subs.o func.o maina.o
        gfortran -o final.x subs.o func.o maina.o
subs.o: subs.f90
        gfortran -c subs.f90
func.o: func.f90
        gfortran -c func.f90
maina.o: maina.f90
        gfortran -c maina.f90
```

after running this, my maina.f90 was deleted and the I did not have a copy. this was what it showed when it was running. (The first output is when I ran it and found an error in subs, and after fixing these errors, I got the second output)

```
$ make
gfortran -o final.x subs.o func.o maina.o
subs.o: In function `__subs_MOD_gauss':
subs.f90:(.text+0x350): undefined reference to `f_'
subs.f90:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `f_'
subs.o: In function `__subs_MOD_simp':
subs.f90:(.text+0x434): undefined reference to `f_'
subs.f90:(.text+0x4a2): undefined reference to `f_'
subs.f90:(.text+0x51b): undefined reference to `f_'
subs.o:subs.f90:(.text+0x571): more undefined references to `f_' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [final.x] Error 1

$ make
gfortran -c subs.f90
gfortran -o final.x subs.o func.o maina.o
```

does anyone know why this file deleted my maina.f90, or (though it's probably unlikely) how to get my work back?

EDIT- I should add that I do not have admin or sudo privileges on this computer

Comment: " how to get my work back?" - use a program like Piriform Recuva. And 
 in future, use source-control like Git.

Comment: Are you sure that's the `makefile` that's being used?  The output from the `make` invocation isn't what I'd expect from a clean build.  The fact that only `subs.o` was recompiled suggests that `func.o` and `maina.o` were already up to date, so I suspect something else has clobbered `maina.f90` -- not the `makefile`.

Comment: Sorry, this was the second time that the makefile was compiled the first time, there was an error in subs, so I had to recompile it for only subs. I'll edit the question so as to not be misleading

Comment: FWIW, there's no way that the makefile shown here would have deleted the `maina.f90` file.  So, if that file disappeared something else, not the makefile or the commands that make invoked (assuming you're not using some bizarre `gfortran` that behaves differently than the standard one), deleted it.  In fact, that file must have existed when the above `make` command was invoked, otherwise it would have failed (given the makefile you have included here).